# My python code for a bitcoin wallet website can't seem to find my wallet.dat bitcoin core file?

Tags: python, bitcoin, bitcoinlib

I'm trying to create a bitcoin wallet website and I've written some python code so far.

I have downloaded bitcoin core and have created a wallet in the directory:
C:\Users\MylesUsername\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\wallets\test2 In which I can see my wallet.dat file but when I try to run my python code I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MylesUsername\Desktop\app.py", line 11, in <module>
    wallet = Wallet(wallet_name)
  File "C:\Users\MylesUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bitcoinlib\wallets.py", line 1408, in __init__
    raise WalletError("Wallet '%s' not found, please specify correct wallet ID or name." % wallet)
bitcoinlib.wallets.WalletError: Wallet 'C:\Users\MylesUsername\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\wallets\test2\wallet.dat' not found, please specify correct wallet ID or name.
```

so it seems my python code can't find the wallet.dat file? I also don't know why it's mentioning the bitcoinlib directory at the start?

This is the python code for my bitcoin wallet website so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from bitcoinlib.wallets import Wallet

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'  # Change this to a secret key

# Provide the name or ID of the wallet
wallet_name = 'C:\\Users\\MylesUsername\\AppData\\Roaming\\Bitcoin\\wallets\\test2\\wallet.dat'  # Change this to your actual wallet name or ID

# Create a Wallet object
wallet = Wallet(wallet_name)

# User data (this should be stored securely in a database in a production environment)
users = {
    'user1': {
        'password': 'password1',
        'address': wallet.get_key().address  # Generate a Bitcoin address for the user
    }
}

# Check if the user is logged in
def is_user_logged_in():
    return 'username' in session

# Create a root route
@app.route('/')
def home():
    if is_user_logged_in():
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return "Welcome to the Bitcoin Flask app!"

# Create a login page
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if is_user_logged_in():
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if username in users and users[username]['password'] == password:
            session['username'] = username  # Store the username in the session
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            return render_template('login.html', error='Invalid username or password.')

    return render_template('login.html')

# Create a dashboard page
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    if not is_user_logged_in():
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    
    username = session['username']
    address = users[username]['address']
    balance = wallet.balance()

    return render_template('dashboard.html', username=username, address=address, balance=balance)

# Create a send Bitcoin page
@app.route('/send', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send():
    if not is_user_logged_in():
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        to_address = request.form['to_address']
        amount = float(request.form['amount'])

        # Send the Bitcoin
        txid = wallet.send_to(to_address, amount, fee='normal')

        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('send.html')

# Create a reset password page
@app.route('/reset_password', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password():
    if not is_user_logged_in():
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    username = session['username']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_password = request.form['new_password']
        
        if len(new_password) < 8:
            return render_template('reset_password.html', error='New password must be at least 8 characters long.')

        users[username]['password'] = new_password

        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('reset_password.html')

# Create a create account page (only for demonstration, not a production-ready solution)
@app.route('/create_account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_account():
    if is_user_logged_in():
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if len(username) < 4 or len(password) < 8:
            return render_template('create_account.html', error='Username must be at least 4 characters and password at least 8 characters.')

        if username in users:
            return render_template('create_account.html', error='Username already taken')

        users[username] = {
            'password': password,
            'address': wallet.get_key().address
        }

        session['username'] = username

        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('create_account.html')

# Logout
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've check my bitcoin core software and it seems to be running fine and has completed downloading everything.

I've added a bitcoin.conf file to my bitcoin core folder which allows rpc.

I've made sure the wallet isn't encrypted

Comment: The `bitcoinlib` package was mentioned because the error occured at creating a wallet: `wallet = Wallet(wallet_name)`. The rest of Flask code were not executed. Please, make sure that your wallet file exists. To isolate the problem, run and debug only the wallet creation code.

Comment: You should not use full path as `wallet_name`.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg This python file is on my desktop & the full path for the wallet.dat file is C:\\Users\\MylesUsername\\AppData\\Roaming\\Bitcoin\\wallets\\test2     What is your suggestion instead of using this full path? I don't understand  (also thanks for your help)

Answer (score 0):

Using bitcoinlib you don't have to use the wallet.dat file as a parameter for the wallet function.
According to the [documentation](https://bitcoinlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/bitcoinlib.wallets.html#module-bitcoinlib.wallets) the function takes a name as parameter to create the wallet object.

Example from the documentation:

```py
wif = 'xprv9s21ZrQH143K3cxbMVswDTYgAc9CeXABQjCD9zmXCpXw4MxN93LanEARbBmV3utHZS9Db4FX1C1RbC5KSNAjQ5WNJ1dDBJ34PjfiSgRvS8x'
if wallet_delete_if_exists('bitcoinlib_legacy_wallet_test', force=True):
    w = Wallet.create('bitcoinlib_legacy_wallet_test', wif)
```

If you want to import the current wallet that you have created in bitcoincore application you can use the `import_key` [method on the wallet object created with the library](https://bitcoinlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/bitcoinlib.wallets.html#bitcoinlib.wallets.Wallet.import_key).